# Drawing a line in tikz using yshift

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a line from a point to a position 1cm above that point, but the following code doesn't seem to work. I would have thought that the yshift does the trick, but no line appears.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[A4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat} %This seems to be necessary with covington
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newsavebox{\partbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
    
\begin{document}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \tikznode{CP1}[\textsubscript{CP} John wonders \tikznode{CP2}[\textsubscript{CP} \tikznode{where}where Mary bought \tikznode{what}what ]] 
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,rounded corners,>=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
        \draw[red,dashed,->] (what) -- +(0,+0.6) -| (CP1);
        \draw[double] ([yshift=1cm] where) -- (where);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Notice that the optional parameter to your tikznode macro should come first... And that you can't nest tikzpicture ever.

Comment: I suggest you look at `tikzmark` package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `tikzmark` Ti*k*Z library:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{itemize}
%\item[] 
    \tikzmarknode{CP1}{[}\textsubscript{CP} John wonders [\textsubscript{CP} 
    \tikzmarknode{where}{where} Mary bought 
    \tikzmarknode{what}{what}.
%\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
                    rounded corners, >=stealth, 
                    shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,
                    thick]
\draw[red,dashed,->] (what.north) -- +(0,+0.6) -| (CP1);
\draw[double] (where.north) ++ (0,1.2) -- (where);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
If in above MWE replace code line

```
\draw[double] (where.north) ++ (0,1.2) -- (where);
```

with

```
\draw[double] (where.north) ++ (0,1.1) -- + (0,-1);
```

then (according to my tase) the produced image is a wee bit nicer:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are using your `\tikznode` incorrectly. It has two arguments, a node name and a text that you want to put into the node, plus an optional argument that can pass options to the node. Your usage is completely strange --- the first `\tikznode` for example has as arguments `CP1` and `[`, the second one `CP2` and `[`, and the third one `where` and `w`, which I suppose is not what you meant (I was wrong, there were no nested `tikz` calls!)

But the main problem because the `[yshfit=1cm]` does not work  in your code is because the `(where)` is not a coordinate, but a node name. You have to pass a coordinate here:

```
\draw[double] ([yshift=1cm] where.north) -- (where);
```

notice that the second `(where)` is ok --- a plain `(node)` is substituted automatically by the border anchor --- that is, the point that connects the start of the line to the center of the node, situated on the border. I added a visible border to the node to show it (notice that it does not touch the borders for the `shorten` options), and put just the "where" in the node... but I have no idea about the semantic of this!

BTW: thanks to [Markus G.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593494/38080) to clean your example of unrelated packages.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \tikznode{CP1}{\textsubscript{CP}} John wonders
             \tikznode{CP2}{\textsubscript{CP}}
             \tikznode[draw, blue]{where}{where} 
             Mary bought \tikznode{what}{what}
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,rounded corners,>=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
        \draw[red,dashed,->] (what) -- +(0,+0.6) -| (CP1);
        \draw[double] ([yshift=1cm] where.north) -- (where);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this solution using tikzlibrary `calc` is something that solves your problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] \tikznode{CP1}[\textsubscript{CP} John wonders \tikznode{CP2}[\textsubscript{CP} \tikznode{where}where Mary bought \tikznode{what}what ]] 
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,rounded corners,>=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
        \draw[red,dashed,->] (what) -- +(0,+0.6) -| (CP1);
        \draw[double] ($(where)+(0,1cm)$) -- (where);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you have already commented on this in the question, I hope you can appreciate that I didn't actually change this part of the original code. I simply focussed on the issue that was causing a problem. The code did compile without issues, but if you still feel there is an issue in terms of good practice, I invite you to give an answer of your own AND instead of simply pointing out that there is an error, I'd appreciate a constructive suggestion on how to aleviate it.

Comment: sorry --- I didn't mean to be harsh; my apologies. I gave an answer here --- yes, the code compiles but the OP clearly used the `\tikznode` badly. The reason why their `yshift` did not work is explained in my answer. Using `calc` as you did is safer --- the node is equivalent to the center anchor in that case.